# Thunderbird 'Non overridable TLS error occured. ... TLS vers. cert. used by server ... incompatible.'

Tags: server, email, thunderbird, versions

I'm new to this, not changed anything on my machine for years. Last week had online banking security threat and advised I must check antivirus and do full system scan.
Today installed ClamTk and run a few scans. Now Thunderbird don't receive emails giving error as described above. I've uninstalled ClamTk and clamav - I think all of it, thunderbird still reports error. I don't recall as to where I access the email settings and what they should be. Help!

Comment: You got an email telling you to check Linux for virus? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I think you should ignore such emails... Sounds like some kind of scam to me.

Comment: Well I have restored a link to my email account by changing the server name to the same one that shows on my email account in my android phone. Not entirely sure what's happened, amaze myself sometimes. Pretty apprehensive going back into places I'd not seen for many years. Anyway panic over for a little while

Comment: Dave, Alain, It was a paper letter. I reported fraud by phone and had my online banking suspended. Had to wait for letter from bank for instructions to remove the suspension. Typical nonsense - run AV full system scan,  ensure OS security updates are current and check firewall. I'm running 22.04.2 LTS assumed computer secure!